# How to set options for the sbt idea plugin in Play2 framework?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt, sbt-idea

I know that the play framework has their own custom sbt plugin to generate Idea project files and I'm trying to find a way to configure it. I see there are some options available, for instance when I type:

```
[my-play-project] $ idea-include-scala-facet
```

I get

```
[info] false
```

How do i set this option to true using the play console? I haven't been able to find any documentation on how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass this configuration to `PlayProject#settings` in your Build.scala . The following worked for me. You might have to tweak it a bit depending on your setup.

```
import org.sbtidea.SbtIdeaPlugin

val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = SCALA).settings(
  ... some other settings ...,
  SbtIdeaPlugin.includeScalaFacet := true
)
```

To set this option in the play console, do:

```
set org.sbtidea.SbtIdeaPlugin.includeScalaFacet := true
```

You can find the other intellij command settings around here: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/2.0.3/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/PlayCommands.scala#L212

Comment: I was hoping for a way of configuring the options interactively from the play console but you have given me a useful pointer to the relevant code so I'll accept this as an answer.

Comment: Sorry. Missed that. Edited the answer to include how to do that from the play console.